# ESP32-cam - websocket - wifimulti - reconnect

Tags: websocket, arduino, wifi

In general my code works very well with one issue i can't get resolved. My ESP32-cam runs a websocket server streaming the camera to a websocket client. I've improved a bit the wifimulti funktionality with the ability to reconnect in case of a lost wifi connectivity. A simple reboot does the trick. Unfortunally this works only with an active websocket connection. Without a websocket connection the ESP32 doesn't recognize the broken connection and is lost until manual intervention. I can't see the cause for this dependency.

```
#include <ArduinoWebsockets.h>
#include <WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "soc/soc.h"
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"
int led = 4;

WiFiMulti wifiMulti;

int index_html_gz_len = 1176;
const uint8_t index_html_gz[] = {
  0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00, 0x9c, 0x50, 0x72, 0x5f, 0x00, 0xff, 0xb5, 0x56, 0x6d, 0x6f, 0xdb, 0x36, 0x10, 0xfe, 0x2c, 0xff, 0x0a, 0x4e, 0x41, 0x51, 0x07, 0x89, 0x64, 0x27, 0x99, 0xbb, 0x46, 0xb6, 0x03, 0x34, 0x6b, 0x8b, 0x0d, 0x28, 0xd0, 0x61, 0xe9, 0x50, 0xec, 0xd3, 0x40, 0x89, 0x27, 0x9b, 0x0b, 0x45, 0x0a, 0x24, 0x15, 0xc7, 0x1d, 0xfa, 0xdf, 0x7b, 0xa4, 0x24, 0x5b, 0xaa, 0x5d, 0xc7, 0x1d, 0x36, 0x01, 0xb6, 0x28, 0xde, 0x0b, 0x9f, 0x7b, 0xe1, 0x43, 0xce, 0x7e, 0x78, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xe7, 0x0f, 0x7f, 0xfe, 0xf6, 0x86, 0x2c, 0x6d, 0x21, 0x6e, 0x06, 0xb3, 0xf6, 0x05, 0x94, 0xe1, 0xcb, 0xd8, 0xb5, 0x80, 0x9b, 0x41, 0x40, 0x08, 0x71, 0x7f, 0x71, 0x2e, 0xe0, 0x31, 0xca, 0x94, 0xb4, 0x94, 0x4b, 0xd0, 0xe4, 0x9f, 0x41, 0x10, 0x30, 0x6e, 0x4a, 0x41, 0xd7, 0x09, 0x71, 0xb2, 0x29, 0x4e, 0x14, 0x54, 0x2f, 0xb8, 0x8c, 0xac, 0x2a, 0x13, 0xf2, 0x12, 0x0a, 0x37, 0x45, 0x05, 0x5f, 0xc8, 0x88, 0x5b, 0x28, 0x4c, 0x42, 0x32, 0x90, 0x16, 0xb4, 0x9b, 0xf6, 0xde, 0x18, 0xd7, 0x90, 0x59, 0xae, 0x24, 0x4a, 0x94, 0xa8, 0x0a, 0x39, 0x0d, 0x50, 0x14, 0xad, 0x20, 0xbd, 0xe7, 0x36, 0xaa, 0x0c, 0xe8, 0xc8, 0x80, 0x40, 0x95, 0x84, 0x48, 0x25, 0x61, 0x3a, 0x40, 0x2c, 0xfe, 0x89, 0x0a, 0xf5, 0xe9, 0xb0, 0xdc, 0xec, 0x13, 0x07, 0xc1, 0x67, 0xfc, 0x61, 0x30, 0xb8, 0x0c, 0x6a, 0xc5, 0x4a, 0xaa, 0x3c, 0x37, 0x2b, 0x6e, 0xb3, 0xa5, 0x8f, 0xa7, 0x54, 0x86, 0xd7, 0x70, 0x34, 0x08, 0x6a, 0xf9, 0x83, 0xb7, 0x59, 0x71, 0x66, 0x97, 0x09, 0xb9, 0xb8, 0x1c, 0x97, 0x18, 0x64, 0xbb, 0xc4, 0x12, 0xf8, 0x62, 0x89, 0x9e, 0x27, 0x13, 0x37, 0x1b, 0x04, 0x3e, 0xe6, 0x9f, 0xbc, 0x4a, 0x10, 0x08, 0xc8, 0x51, 0x74, 0x35, 0xa9, 0x3f, 0x1d, 0xa0, 0xff, 0x2d, 0xa6, 0x46, 0xfa, 0x79, 0xd0, 0x8e, 0xba, 0x51, 0x45, 0xd9, 0x12, 0xb2, 0xfb, 0x54, 0x3d, 0x62, 0x78, 0xad, 0x1f, 0xb2, 0xa9, 0xda, 0x31, 0x0e, 0x04, 0x4d, 0x41, 0xec, 0xb5, 0x4e, 0x85, 0xca, 0xee, 0xb7, 0xf0, 0x88, 0x7a, 0x00, 0x9d, 0x0b, 0xb5, 0x4a, 0xc8, 0x92, 0x33, 0x06, 0xb2, 0x23, 0xca, 0x2a, 0x6d, 0x94, 0x4e, 0x48, 0xa9, 0x78, 0x5d, 0xff, 0x8d, 0x24, 0x55, 0x9a, 0x01, 0x4a, 0xae, 0xca, 0x47, 0x62, 0x94, 0xe0, 0x8c, 0x9c, 0x5c, 0xfb, 0x67, 0x47, 0x27, 0xd2, 0x94, 0xf1, 0x0a, 0x7b, 0xe8, 0xaa, 0x5b, 0x86, 0x6f, 0xa0, 0xe6, 0xb2, 0x6e, 0xd1, 0xa7, 0x51, 0x37, 0xc5, 0xbd, 0x1c, 0x8f, 0x9f, 0x75, 0x66, 0x9b, 0x3e, 0xae, 0xcb, 0x18, 0x5d, 0xf4, 0x85, 0x56, 0x53, 0xd9, 0xf6, 0x49, 0xad, 0x48, 0xc6, 0xf1, 0x95, 0x21, 0x40, 0x0d, 0xe0, 0xca, 0x64, 0x6c, 0x8e, 0x82, 0x97, 0xa4, 0x90, 0x2b, 0x0d, 0xe7, 0x07, 0x34, 0x68, 0x8e, 0xd9, 0x3a, 0x2a, 0x0c, 0x4c, 0x3c, 0x45, 0xa8, 0x0e, 0xf0, 0x6e, 0x70, 0x93, 0x1e, 0xfc, 0x4d, 0xe3, 0xf6, 0xda, 0x99, 0x94, 0x94, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x17, 0x09, 0x19, 0x77, 0x26, 0x05, 0x6e, 0xf5, 0xe8, 0x1b, 0x06, 0x39, 0x52, 0x41, 0x64, 0xf8, 0x27, 0x70, 0xd9, 0xeb, 0x49, 0x70, 0x2f, 0xbb, 0x6a, 0xaf, 0x96, 0xb8, 0xeb, 0xbf, 0x36, 0xc8, 0x69, 0xc1, 0x05, 0x06, 0xf0, 0x41, 0x43, 0x5a, 0x61, 0x77, 0xda, 0x73, 0xf2, 0x4a, 0x73, 0x2a, 0xce, 0x89, 0xc1, 0xac, 0x62, 0x6f, 0x6b, 0x9e, 0x7f, 0x6d, 0xb3, 0x6a, 0x00, 0xa4, 0x4a, 0xb0, 0x5e, 0x5f, 0x3c, 0xba, 0xf5, 0x3d, 0xe8, 0xa6, 0x47, 0x70, 0xea, 0x7b, 0x72, 0xdf, 0x4d, 0xad, 0x63, 0x36, 0x64, 0xa7, 0x84, 0x84, 0xef, 0x78, 0xb6, 0xb4, 0xe1, 0x6e, 0x6a, 0x9a, 0x76, 0xb8, 0xe8, 0x07, 0x9b, 0xd2, 0xec, 0x7e, 0xa1, 0x55, 0x25, 0x19, 0x92, 0xa3, 0x8f, 0xfb, 0xe4, 0xf2, 0xed, 0xe4, 0xfa, 0xfa, 0xf5, 0x6e, 0x42, 0x4e, 0x72, 0xff, 0x1c, 0x87, 0x70, 0xa7, 0xf6, 0x5b, 0x80, 0xaf, 0xe4, 0x3e, 0x74, 0xba, 0x4e, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0xf0, 0x80, 0x4d, 0xe8, 0x84, 0xee, 0x81, 0xf7, 0xd6, 0x3f, 0xdd, 0x4e, 0x87, 0x47, 0x1b, 0x79, 0x02, 0x47, 0x46, 0x74, 0xee, 0x9f, 0x82, 0xbe, 0xe1, 0xd2, 0xa3, 0x37, 0xde, 0x8f, 0x7d, 0xb8, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0x4a, 0xc8, 0x8b, 0x6f, 0x04, 0xb1, 0x0f, 0xe5, 0x96, 0xb5, 0x69, 0x8a, 0x1c, 0x52, 0xf5, 0x9a, 0xce, 0xd3, 0x72, 0xb7, 0xa5, 0x53, 0x65, 0xad, 0x2a, 0xfa, 0x73, 0x4d, 0xea, 0x5e, 0x7c, 0xb5, 0x6a, 0xc3, 0x4d, 0x97, 0xff, 0x92, 0x9b, 0xfa, 0x4c, 0x41, 0x85, 0xf8, 0x5e, 0x9a, 0x68, 0xc9, 0x3b, 0xf1, 0x03, 0x60, 0x67, 0x7b, 0x98, 0xf9, 0x30, 0xed, 0xf5, 0x78, 0x6c, 0x1b, 0xf1, 0x7f, 0xb5, 0xde, 0x6e, 0xb9, 0x9b, 0x4c, 0xf6, 0x29, 0xba, 0xbd, 0x42, 0x90, 0x58, 0x2b, 0x4b, 0x2d, 0xf0, 0x62, 0x71, 0x3d, 0xf6, 0x07, 0x6e, 0x7b, 0x2c, 0xfa, 0x44, 0xe1, 0x8e, 0x2c, 0x92, 0x5a, 0x63, 0x78, 0x3d, 0x66, 0xb0, 0x38, 0x75, 0x47, 0xa9, 0x3f, 0x16, 0xb7, 0x72, 0xb2, 0x47, 0xc1, 0x1c, 0x96, 0xab, 0x83, 0xe2, 0x03, 0x32, 0x0f, 0x7e, 0x36, 0x6a, 0x2e, 0x42, 0xb3, 0x51, 0x73, 0x31, 0x4a, 0x15, 0x5b, 0xdf, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x33, 0xc6, 0x1f, 0x48, 0x26, 0xa8, 0x31, 0xf3, 0xb0, 0x7f, 0x37, 0x0a, 0x51, 0x1a, 0xcc, 0x30, 0x4a, 0xc2, 0xd9, 0x3c, 0x34, 0x56, 0x03, 0x2d, 0x42, 0x62, 0x74, 0x36, 0x0f, 0xc3, 0xd6, 0xa2, 0x93, 0x09, 0x14, 0xb9, 0x15, 0xe6, 0x61, 0xbd, 0x25, 0xf0, 0x9e, 0xf1, 0x6c, 0x5a, 0xbb, 0xe8, 0xac, 0xd0, 0x49, 0x3b, 0xca, 0x36, 0xf9, 0x26, 0x64, 0xc6, 0x65, 0x59, 0x59, 0x62, 0xd7, 0x25, 0x7a, 0x68, 0x2b, 0x18, 0x12, 0x49, 0x0b, 0xfc, 0xee, 0x5a, 0xed, 0xf1, 0xb4, 0xbd, 0x1e, 0x84, 0x1e, 0x6a, 0xb1, 0xee, 0x1b, 0xd4, 0x6d, 0x30, 0xea, 0xaf, 0x57, 0xf7, 0xc1, 0x1e, 0x67, 0xb5, 0x80, 0x4b, 0x77, 0x68, 0x84, 0xc8, 0xdc, 0x7a, 0xc7, 0xa1, 0x92, 0x99, 0xe0, 0xd9, 0xfd, 0x3c, 0xc4, 0xff, 0xa5, 0xa5, 0x72, 0x78, 0xda, 0x8f, 0x05, 0xbd, 0x9b, 0x92, 0xca, 0x7d, 0xce, 0x7d, 0x6b, 0x87, 0x37, 0x58, 0x0d, 0x54, 0x38, 0xd6, 0xa8, 0xcd, 0xd7, 0x1e, 0xab, 0xd9, 0xc8, 0xc3, 0xad, 0xe7, 0x66, 0x23, 0xcc, 0x34, 0x5e, 0x75, 0x31, 0xe5, 0xcd, 0x68, 0x66, 0x32, 0xcd, 0x4b, 0x8b, 0xa3, 0xbc, 0x92, 0xfe, 0x8a, 0x8a, 0x67, 0x61, 0x83, 0xd9, 0x75, 0xee, 0x03, 0xd5, 0x75, 0x7a, 0x6e, 0x31, 0x79, 0x73, 0xc2, 0x54, 0x56, 0x15, 0x48, 0xce, 0xf1, 0x02, 0xec, 0x1b, 0x01, 0x6e, 0x78, 0xbb, 0xfe, 0x95, 0x0d, 0x9f, 0xf7, 0x12, 0xf0, 0xdc, 0x37, 0x1c, 0xcf, 0xc9, 0xb0, 0x35, 0x8d, 0x9b, 0x14, 0x93, 0xf9, 0x1c, 0xc9, 0xa2, 0x82, 0x53, 0xb7, 0x29, 0x82, 0x95, 0x89, 0x0d, 0x48, 0x36, 0x74, 0x44, 0x7f, 0x3a, 0x75, 0x1b, 0x28, 0x00, 0x61, 0xdc, 0x69, 0xd5, 0x13, 0x56, 0x06, 0xa5, 0x03, 0x14, 0x3b, 0x8d, 0xd1, 0x08, 0x13, 0xc0, 0x1d, 0x84, 0x5a, 0xfa, 0x0b, 0x08, 0xa1, 0xc8, 0x1d, 0x68, 0xbc, 0x95, 0x79, 0xb5, 0xcd, 0x21, 0x62, 0x2c, 0x79, 0xe0, 0xb0, 0x3a, 0x84, 0xba, 0x6e, 0x59, 0x07, 0xb7, 0x67, 0xf6, 0xf1, 0xee, 0xaf, 0x3f, 0x7e, 0x7f, 0x87, 0x86, 0xe1, 0xca, 0x24, 0xa3, 0x51, 0x48, 0xce, 0x90, 0xc5, 0x25, 0x53, 0xab, 0x18, 0xb9, 0x1d, 0xaf, 0xcb, 0x4a, 0xc6, 0x4b, 0x85, 0x7a, 0x67, 0x24, 0x4c, 0x5e, 0x5e, 0x6e, 0xcf, 0xa8, 0xda, 0x7a, 0x65, 0xd0, 0x52, 0xe2, 0xc2, 0x1f, 0x21, 0xbd, 0xc3, 0xb3, 0x00, 0xec, 0xb0, 0x76, 0x88, 0xcb, 0xb4, 0x9a, 0x18, 0x9c, 0x92, 0x05, 0x18, 0x43, 0x17, 0x80, 0xda, 0x9b, 0xd1, 0x4d, 0x97, 0x63, 0x5c, 0x02, 0x1b, 0x49, 0xcc, 0xa8, 0xa5, 0xd8, 0x72, 0x06, 0x0b, 0x93, 0x81, 0xca, 0xc9, 0xad, 0x50, 0xa9, 0x2b, 0x50, 0xa7, 0xd2, 0xae, 0x54, 0x95, 0x16, 0xef, 0xd3, 0xbf, 0xf1, 0xd6, 0x8c, 0x4e, 0x71, 0xc5, 0x38, 0xc3, 0xf8, 0x2c, 0xd4, 0x53, 0xf8, 0xdd, 0x73, 0xb7, 0x8d, 0xda, 0x5b, 0x63, 0xaa, 0x62, 0xdc, 0xba, 0x68, 0xb8, 0x71, 0xd2, 0x51, 0xc0, 0xe4, 0x37, 0x83, 0xa9, 0x63, 0x8a, 0xa6, 0x69, 0x70, 0x58, 0x93, 0x04, 0x72, 0x86, 0x2d, 0xc4, 0x17, 0x9e, 0x48, 0xad, 0x58, 0x69, 0x0d, 0x00, 0x00
};

#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27
#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;

using namespace websockets;
WebsocketsServer WSserver;
AsyncWebServer webserver(80);

void setup() {
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0); //disable brownout detector
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Ai-Thinker: pins 2 and 4
  ledcSetup(2, 50, 16); //channel, freq, resolution
  ledcAttachPin(2, 2);  // pin, channel
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); // pin4 led

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  //init with high specs to pre-allocate larger buffers

  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SXGA;
  config.jpeg_quality = 10;
  config.fb_count = 2;

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }

  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_SVGA);

  wifiMulti.addAP("ssid_from_AP_1", "your_password_for_AP_1");
  wifiMulti.addAP("ssid_from_AP_2", "your_password_for_AP_2");
  wifiMulti.addAP("ssid_from_AP_3", "your_password_for_AP_3");

  Serial.println("Connecting Wifi...");
  if (wifiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.print("SSID: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  }

  webserver.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
    AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse_P(200, "text/html", index_html_gz, sizeof(index_html_gz));
    response->addHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    request->send(response);
  });

  webserver.begin();
  WSserver.listen(82);
  Serial.print("WSserver alive!");
  Serial.println(WSserver.available());
}
int main() {
  while (WSserver.available()) {
    // accept another client
    WebsocketsClient client = WSserver.accept();

    // wait for a message for the client and send an echo response
    auto message = client.readBlocking();
    client.send("Echo: " + message.data());
    Serial.println(message.data());

    // close the connection
    client.close();
  }
}

void handle_message(WebsocketsMessage msg) {

  Serial.println(msg.data());
  //Serial.println(tiltValue);
  if (msg.data() == "Aus") {
    digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);

  }
}
void loop() {

  if (wifiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi not connected!");
    delay(500);
    WiFi.disconnect();
    Serial.println("\nReboot");
    ESP.restart();
  }

  auto client = WSserver.accept();
  client.onMessage(handle_message);
  while (client.available()) {
    client.poll();
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    client.sendBinary((const char *)fb->buf, fb->len);
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
    fb = NULL;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems not the right place for question like these. After some try and error i got it running. Two functions called in the void loop did the job.

```
        void camera() {

      if (WSserver.poll())
      {
      auto client = WSserver.accept();
        if (client.available()) 
        {
          client.onMessage(handle_message);
           while(client.available())
           {
        client.poll();
        fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
        client.sendBinary((const char *)fb->buf, fb->len);
        esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
        fb = NULL;
      }
    }  
    }
    }
    void wifireconnect() {

      if (wifiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.println("WiFi not connected!");
        delay(500);
        WiFi.disconnect();
        Serial.println("\nReboot");
        ESP.restart();
      }
    }
      
    void loop() {

    camera();

    wifireconnect();
      }
```